# Js not work for form ui component in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I created JS for submit ajax to search for product names, it didn't work, I think because when reloading the page, the form was not created yet. and no `input[name$='general[product_id]']`

My js

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'],function($) {

jQuery("document").ready(function(){
    jQuery("input[name$='general[product_id]']").change(function() {
        var productId = jQuery("input[name$='general[product_id]']").val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/index/index/searchnameproduct",
            dataType: 'json',
            type : 'post',
            data: {productId: productId},
            showLoader: true,
            success: function(data) {
                // var returnedData = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first check if your element binding is working right.
If this `input[name$='general[product_id]']` is a dynamically created element then you need to change

```
jQuery("input[name$='general[product_id]']").change(function() {
```

to

```
jQuery("input[name$='general[product_id]']").on('change',function() {
```

or even more to

```
jQuery("body").on('change',"input[name$='general[product_id]']",function() {
```

Hope it might help

Comment: if copy it and paste to console tab, it's work

Comment: @TN98 something working in console is not the same as working in browser run time

Comment: yes, it not work after browser run

Comment: try the changes as I mentioned @TN98

Comment: it also not work :(

Comment: ah, it work for me, i used jQuery("body").on('change',"input[name$='general[product_id]']",function()

Comment: Thank u very much ^^ have a nice day

Comment: Welcome and Happy coding